# Rails: call link_to in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, oauth

I want to put a `link_to` call with an argument into a controller like so (`twitter` is an argument in the `authorise` route):

```
def method
  "/authorise/twitter"
  ...
end
```

I don't mind copying the authorise method to make it happen, but I don't know how to pass the `twitter` argument to that method.

```
def authorise
  user = User.from_omniauth(current_user, env['omniauth.auth'])
  session[:user_id] = current_user.id
end
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here's the route I'm trying to replicate in a way in the controller method:

```
get '/authorise/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#authorise'
```

And here's the `from_omniauth` method:

```
def self.from_omniauth(user, auth)
  user.provider = auth.provider
  if auth.provider == "facebook"
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
  elsif auth.provider == "twitter"
    user.access_token = auth["credentials"]["token"]
    user.access_token_secret = auth["credentials"]["secret"]
  end
  user.save!
end
```

It should be passing `'twitter'` to the `auth` argument, but I get this error:

```
undefined method `provider' for "twitter":String
app/models/user.rb:82:in `from_omniauth'
```

It feels like I should be passing a hash or similar, but I can't figure out what that should be. It now feels like an oauth-specific thing.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't pass arguments to a rails actions, you can, indeed pass them to  methods in a controller.

Stepping back from your question, I believe you're asking how to reuse a controller method. Generally, you'd want to avoid copying a method - keeping it [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). I would break out your authorize action into a separate method.

Your code could look like this:

```
def new_method
  authorize_from_strategy('twitter')
end

def authozie #old method
  authorize_from_strategy
end

private 

def authorize_from_strategy(strategy=nil)
  user = User.from_omniauth(current_user, strategy || env['omniauth.auth'])
  session[:user_id] = current_user.id
end
```

If you wanted to use the `authorize_from_strategy` method in any controller, you could move that private action to your application_controller.

Also, setting `session[:user_id]` might be redundant if you're using something like devise.  Devise stores your user's info in the session already, which is how you have access to `current_user`.

Comment: That definitely feels like the right track. Passing the string seems to fail though, and I can't figure out why. Can I ask you what the `...=nil` part does?

Comment: `=nil` means you can optionally submit a default value.  If the argument is absent, the default value is used. I made a mistake (updated above). The first line of the private method should have had an optional fallback.  I meant to add a `(current_user, strategy || env['omniauth.auth'])`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the string failing.  Also, here is an article on ruby arguments that may be useful to you: http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/method-arguments-in-ruby/

Comment: It fails in `from_omniauth` because `'twitter'` is a string, it seems. But since it would have been a string in the view in the initial link I'm not sure what to update it to. I'll update the question with detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass arguments for a controller action, but you can pass **request params** into the controller. So something like:

```
def method
  @twitter = Your_Model.find params[:twitter]
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That does make a little bit of sense, but I'm trying to send `twitter` to the authorise method and not retrieve a record with those params. The `Your_Model` in this case doesn't exist, there's only a controller for it.